# Under sink leak

Tags: kitchen-sink, leaking

I just redid my kitchen cabinets, including changing to a new sink. The photo shows the pipe from the sink going to the floor.

I called the contractor to see if there's anything we can do. He came by to cement this up but now it is still leaking despite the cement.

Help me guys!

[image]

Comment: You or someone else has to find out where the water's coming from and then stop it from leaking. That's the first order of business.  What ype of connection is that?

Comment: Is that a droplet of water from the leak, above the collar?

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of plumbing this is. Why don't we see signs of primer or cement at the top of the coupler? Some context would be great.